# Can you use moneris with CiviCRM?

Tags: payment-processor, moneris

Is there a CiviCRM extension that supports the moneris payment gateway?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Yes - this is where you can find the [Moneris payment processor extension](https://github.com/adixon/ca.civicrm.moneris).

Comment: Note it replaces the old one shipped w/ Core;